# Wpf bind string to the name property

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a button in a dynamically loaded XAML file.

```
<Button Name="{Binding Template_Text1}"
        Width="800" Height="76"
        Content="{Binding Template_Text1}"
        Style="{DynamicResource RoundedButton}"/>
```

If I give a static NAME to the button everything goes ok.
so, how can I bind a string variable to the NAME property?

Comment: Databindings can only be used with dependency properties, and the name isn't one of them

Comment: Name is a Dependency property but a very special one. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

[From the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name.aspx):

> Name is one of the very few dependency properties that cannot be
>   animated ( IsAnimationProhibited is true in metadata), because the
>   name itself is vital for targeting an animation. Data binding a Name
>   is technically possible, but is an extremely uncommon scenario because
>   a data-bound Name cannot serve the main intended purpose of the
>   property: to provide an identifier connection point for code-behind.

In other words: what you are doing is very tricky so think again whether or not you really need it.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping @Erno's valuable input in mind above, I think you can **change** Name of a property via binding through an attached behavior.

```
   <Button local:NameAnimationBehavior.Name="{Binding Template_Text1}" ... />
```

And inside the `NameAnimationBehavior`, in `NameProperty`'s dependency property changed handler, change the sender's `Name` property with `e.NewValue`.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will use custom properties to store the info I need.